# Variable is Undefined

Tags: javascript, html, undefined

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<HEAD>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lb-core.js"></script>
<script type="application/javascript">
var lbp = {
    defaults: {
        color: "blue"
    },
    init: function(config) {
        if(config) {
            for(prop in config){
                setBgcolor.defaults[prop] = config[prop];
            }
        }
        var bod = document.body;
        bod.style.backgroundColor = setBgcolor.defaults.color;
    }
}
window.onload = lbp.init();
</script>
</HEAD>
<body>
<div id="container">test</div>
</body>
</HTML>
```

Why does bod come back as undefined when the above is called at window.onload?

Comment: It would help if you posted more of the Javascript and the HTML also. One possibility is that your code is *not* running in the onload handler, but instead is running when a script tag in the head is parsed (before the body tag has been seen).

Comment: Try putting your script after the body tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code needs a few teaks, here's an overall fix:

```
var lbp = {
    defaults: {
        color: "blue"
    },
    init: function(config) {
        if(config) {
            for(prop in config){
                lbp.defaults[prop] = config[prop];
            }
        }
        var bod = document.body;
        bod.style.backgroundColor = lbp.defaults.color;
    }
}
window.onload = lbp.init;
```

Previous it was calling `init` instantly because `window.onload = lbp.init()` was assigning the **result** of `lbp.init` to the onload function, not assigning the actual function, this is fixed above.

Also, not sure where `setBgcolor` comes from in your code, I believe you meant `lbp` here, it works in the same code above, give it a test.

Comment: Yeah, I realized those other config calls too after body was working. Thanks!

Comment: Nick - if I don't use parens in window.onload = lbp.init, how am I supposed to pas in config, which would override the default configurations?

Comment: @Matrym - You can use an anonymous function, like this: `window.onload = function() { lbp.init({ optionsHere }); };`

Answer (score 3):

Change it to

```
window.onload = lbp.init;
```

When you write `window.onload = lbp.init()`, you are *calling* the `init` function, and assigning whatever it returns to `window.onload`.
Therefore, the function is being called *immediately* (before the window is loaded), and you're assigning `undefined` to `window.onload`.  (Because `init` doesn't return anything)

You need to assign the `init` function itself to `onload` without calling it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`var bod = document.body;`

I don't know why `bod` comes back as undefined in your code.. it works for me in Chrome. What browser are you running?

Also, are you sure it's `bod` that's undefined? Not `setBgcolor` or something else?

**EDIT**:

Change this line of code:

`window.onload = lbp.init();`

To this:

`window.onload = lbp.init;`

You're currently assigning the **result** of lpd.init() to `onload`.. you need to just assign the reference.